# Call this.setState inside not arrow function?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a [library](https://github.com/js1016/txt-reader) for working with the content of files. I'm using the `function` instead of `arrow function` because I need to access the `decode method`. But then I want to set the result of a function to a state of the component. But of course, in that case, this is not pointing to the component anymore.

I'm not sure what to do there?

```
reader.loadFile(file)
                    .then((response) =>  {
                        reader.iterateLines({
                            eachLine: function (raw, progress, lineNumber)  {
                                console.log(this.decode(raw))
                                this.setState({
                                    txtFileContent: this.decode(raw)
                                });
                            },
                        })
                    })
                    .catch( (reason): void => {
                        console.log(this);
                    });
```

Comment: Outside the function, assign `this` to a different variable and reference that instead. See [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1):

assign this to that while you are still capable:

```js
const that = this;
```

Later, inside the scope where this is no longer the 'this' you wanted, so you can still call it's methods.

```js
that.setState(....);
```

Remember, 'that' is a generic proposal, any semantic name for this constant will a better option.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, use functional react component with `useState` hook, and get rid of context problems! https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 0):

When creating the function that you want to use as a callback, bind `this` to it, as such:

```
eachLine: (function (raw, progress, lineNumber)  {
    console.log(this.decode(raw))
    this.setState({
        txtFileContent: this.decode(raw)
    });
}).bind(this),
```

Answer (score -1):

Try binding `this`

```
this.setState.bind(this, { txtFileContent: this.decode(raw) })
```

Comment: How/where/when should this be applied? `.bind` returns a new function.

Comment: Given the second argument you pass to `.bind`, this proposal makes no sense. `this` cannot refer to two different values at the same time, but that's what your proposal is implying (since you are referring to `this.decode` and `this.setState` which live on different objects, as per OP's problem description).

Comment: would do const update = this.setState.bind(this); and then calling update(newState) ?

Comment: This can be solution with this approach. In outer scope we can define setState function `const setState = this.setState.bind(this)`;